# Cokernel in abelian category is epic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-categories

Prove that cokernel in abelian Category is epic.

$\mathbf{My\  attempt}$

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$ and $f:A \rightarrow $ be a morphism, and and $g:B \rightarrow C$ such that $gf=0$ for some $B \in \mathcal{C}.$ Let $h_1,h_2: C \rightarrow D$ such that $h_1 g=h_2 g$. We know that $h_1gf=h_1(0)=h_2gf=h_2(0),$ but this is not enough to show $g_1=g_2$. I could not go forward from this, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the cokernel of $f:A \to B$ is the following : a morphism $g : B \to C$ such that for any $g^\prime : B \to D$ with $g^\prime \circ  f=0$, there exists a $\textbf{unique}$ $\phi : C \to D$ such that $g^\prime= \phi \circ g$.

So for any $h:C \to D$, if $h \circ g=0$ then letting $g^\prime=h \circ g: B \to D$, we have  $g ^\prime \circ f=0$. Since $g$ is the cokernel of $f$, there is a unique $\phi : C \to D$ such that $\phi \circ g=g^\prime$. But $\phi=0$ and $\phi=h$ are possible solutions, so they are equal, that is $h=0$. We show that way that $g$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: what if $h \circ g \neq 0?$

Comment: In an abelian category, to show that a morphism $g$ is an epimorphism, one just has to show that $\forall h, \, h \circ g=0 \Rightarrow h=0$. This is equivalent to $\forall ( h_1, h_2), \, h_1 \circ g=h_2 \circ g \Rightarrow h_1=h_2$

Comment: Thank you, you ment $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: No I really meant $\Rightarrow$. The $\Leftarrow$ is obvious

Comment: Got it thanks a lot